# How to remove xmlns:ns2 from body tag in SOAP request?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jax-ws, soap-client

My SOAP request is generated as bellow

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body xmlns:ns2="http://www.myserviceABC.com/application/ws/service">
      <ns2:getStatus>
         <pRef>123</pRef>
      </ns2:getStatus>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I want to remove **xmlns:ns2="http://www.myserviceABC.com/application/ws/service"** from **body tag** and add it to **getStatus** tag as bellow

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getStatus xmlns:ns2="http://www.myserviceABC.com/application/ws/service">
         <pRef>123</pRef>
      </ns2:getStatus>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Can someone please tell me know to do this?

Better if I can use the SOAPHandler

Comment: What Java objects do you currently have available to you?

Comment: I am generating the stub from the wsdl. So I have all the Generated Java classes with the SOAPHandler

Comment: Perhaps a better question is:  Why do you want to do this?  The body XML is functionally identical either way.  If you’re trying to isolate the body content, use an XML API, not string truncation or regular expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a standard that I have to follow in this case

Answer (score 1):

The classes you generated from your WSDL should include a subclass of [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html).

Call [Service.setHandlerResolver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#setHandlerResolver-javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver-) with a custom HandlerResolver that returns a Handler which alters the message’s body:

```
    HandlerResolver originalResolver = myService.getHandlerResolver();

    myService.setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolver() {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo info) {
            Handler handler = new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
                @Override
                public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
                    return Collections.emptySet();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
                    SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();

                    try {
                        if (moveNamespaceToDocument(message,
                            "http://www.myserviceABC.com/application/ws/service")) {

                            context.setMessage(message);
                        }
                    } catch (SOAPException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void close(MessageContext context) {
                    // Deliberately empty
                }
            };

            List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>(
                originalResolver.getHandlerChain(info));
            handlers.add(handler);
            return handlers;
        }
    });

// ...

private static boolean moveNamespaceToDocument(SOAPMessage message,
                                               String namespaceURI)
throws SOAPException {
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
    if (body.hasFault()) {
        return false;
    }

    Attr namespaceAttr = null;

    NamedNodeMap attributes = body.getAttributes();
    int count = attributes.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Attr attr = (Attr) attributes.item(i);
        String name = attr.getName();
        if (name.startsWith("xmlns:") &&
            namespaceURI.equals(attr.getValue())) {

            namespaceAttr = attr;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (namespaceAttr == null) {
        return false;
    }

    NodeList children = body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    if (children.getLength() < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    Element root = (Element) children.item(0);

    body.removeAttributeNode(namespaceAttr);
    root.setAttributeNode(namespaceAttr);

    return true;
}
```

I can verify that the `moveNamespaceToDocument` method works, but I don’t have an easy way to test this with an actual Service, so I’m not certain about the HandlerResolver.

Comment: This works perfect with one little change. Instead of context.setMessage(message), please use message.saveChanges() instead.